# Почему при старте WebAPI не выводится информация на консоль c# ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

При разработке WebAPI столкнулся с тем, что при запуске не выводится никакая информация на консоль вида:
[image: Консоль]

Я полез в файл launchSettings.json чтобы проверить свойство `dotnetRunMessages`, но оно установлено везде в true:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57058",
      "sslPort": 44329
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5197",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7243;http://localhost:5197",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Логи настроены с помощью Serilog:

```
builder.Services.AddSerilog(loggerConfig =>
    loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));
```

Файл конфигурации:

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [
    "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
    "Serilog.Sinks.File"
  ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "logs/log-.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
}
```

При этом в другом проекте с точно такой конфигурацией лога все выводится, при том не зависит от свойства `dotnetRunMessages`. В общем я обнаружил что совершенно не знаю откуда берется это сообщение в консоли при запуске. Объясните как его настроить?

Comment: Сталкивался с таким, но при условии, что запускаешь проект из студии и после запуска консоль появляется, но сам сервис не поднимается(не отвечает на запросы). Лечилось закрытием консоли и перезапуском. Если это не то. то я бы сначала попробовал запустить без Serilog, чтобы удостоверится что это не он отсеивает сообщения

Comment: @Vasek я уже понял что это настройки Log левелов надо поменять. Понять бы как правильно. Пока отложил данный вопрос.